# Terraform and GCP - Create new Compute VM in existing Shared VPC and Subnet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

How do I create a new Compute Instance and associate it with an existing shared VPC/Subnet? The shared VPC/Subnet already exists in another Project.

My TF block:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "computevm1" {
  name                      = "test-compute-vm1"
  zone                      = "us-west1-a"
  machine_type              = "e2-standard-1"

  network_interface {
    network = "isolated-vpc"
  }
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "ubuntu-2004-focal-v20211212"
      size  = 20
    }
  }
}
```

Error I'm getting:

```
The referenced network resource cannot be found., invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

For HCL attribute **network** specify the network name of the VPC in the project that the instance is being created in. The subnet will be selected from the region automatically. There is nothing special about Shared VPC when creating an instance.

Assuming your Shared VPC is enabled on the default network:

```
network_interface {
  network = "default"
}
```

Change the name if different.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. I have a network that is already created in another project and is shared to my project that I'm creating this new instance. How does Terraform know to associate the new instance with the shared network?

And putting "default" did not work.

`Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].network': 'projects/project-name/global/networks/default'. The referenced network resource cannot be found`

Comment: @BenVek Use the actual name of the network that the VM instance is being created in. The network must already exist. The VM does not care about shared/peered networks. Just select the correct network in the HCL.

Comment: The shared network already exists. I did include the network name and got the same error. `network_interface {   network = "NAME OF SHAREDVPC" }`

Comment: @BenVek - You are doing something wrong with the name. In your question list the actual names of all networks in the project that you are creating the VM within. There is no security benefit to **masking** the names. Use the actual values in your question and comments.

Comment: the shared VPC network name is "isolated-vpc"
the subnet name is "isolated-net"

`network_interface {
  network = "isolated-vpc"
}`

Comment: @BenVek I see your update. Use the CLI or the GUI and list the networks in the project. Another item, your HCL does not show which project you are using. The network must be in the project that Terrarm is using to create the instance. The error message means you are not doing that.

Comment: This is precisely my point. There are zero networks in my project. I'm trying to use a shared network which is in a "different project" - It's shared with my project (I'm the consumer).

If you go to the GCP Console --> VPC Networks, you will see two tabs:

a) NETWORKS IN CURRENT PROJECTS. 

b) NETWORKS SHARED TO MY PROJECT. 

How do I define in Terraform to use (b)?

Comment: @BenVek - you cannot create a VM instance using B. You must use a VPC in your current project - otherwise, create the VM in the project hosting the shared VPC. You can use VPC peering to connect that VPC to a Shared VPC. Peering is a service to route packets between VPC. The Shared VPC is like a hub that other VPCs can connect to.

Comment: @BenVek Were you able to resolve this issue, I'm also stuck with the same question. Thanks.

Comment: @Vikram - I still haven't found a solution to this. Maybe defining the organization in Terraform might work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use data to import the nework and subnet in your tf file like

```
data "google_compute_network" "main-default-vpc" {
  name    = "default"
  project = "project-id"
}

data "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet-for-vms" {
  name    = "name_of_subnet"
  project = "project-id"
  region  = "us-central1"

network_interface {
  subnetwork = data.google_compute_subnetwork.subnet-for-vms
  }
```

For more information; take a look at https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/get-started-with-terraform

@BenVek; let me know if it works or not. I have faced similar issues and that is how I solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).